# Put Gmail Tasks (todo list) into the sidebar, not as a floating window

Tags: gmail

By default, if you click the "Gmail" in the upper-left corner, and select *Tasks*, you'll get a pop-up window in the bottom-right corner with the todo-list.

It can be minimised, but then the tasks aren't visible, which makes it less useful. Keeping it open is a problem, because it blocks a part of the Inbox, and just gets in the way visually.

Is there a way to have the "Tasks" list, or something like it, but which fits into the sidebar on the left, under the menu, i.e. as an alternative to the Chat list?

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to display this very same *Tasks* gadget inside the sidebar, rather than an overlaid window.

1. *Settings* > *Labs* > Enable *Add any gadget by URL*
2. Go to *Gadgets* tab and enter the URL `http://www.google.com/ig/modules/tasks.xml` . Click *Add*.

Done!

[image]

Reference: http://www.keanei.com/2011/11/04/adding-google-tasks-to-the-main-gmail-window/

Comment: Perfect! Is there a way to adjust the length of the task list?

Comment: @jaydeepsb It scrolls when it gets too long. I keep it short — just to remember stuff to do at home (when at work) and vice versa.

Comment: Sidebar gadgets are deprecated and not supported anymore https://developers.google.com/gmail/sidebar_gadgets 'Add any gadget by URL' is not available anymore...

Answer (score 1):

As of now Gmail sidebar gadgets are deprecated and will soon cease to be supported.

But there is a chrome addon called **[RightTasks for Gmail™.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/righttasks-for-gmail/hgniockidojcaaolfcbbkaaakbjdebpe)**

> Adds your Google Tasks to a right sidebar in Gmail, like in Google Calendar.
>   RightTasks places your Google Tasks in a right sidebar in Gmail, like in Google Calendar.

[image: RightTasks]

Reference:
https://github.com/ghinda/gmail-righttasks

Answer (score 0):

With the new Gmail (Google is about to get rid of Inbox), you can get your tasks fixed to the right hand side as long as you move your chat window to the left (standard).
If you leave your chat on the right, the tasks will keep opening on a floating window